# How to access a cookie in jquery from Symfony2

Tags: jquery, cookies, symfony

So I want a controller in Symfony2 to set a cookie, then have a jquery script act accordingly if that cookie has been set.  It seems straightforward, but since I can't get it to work, I thought I'd ask.

Here is my Symfony code to set a cookie:

```
// in controller
    $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('_fs_feed_show');
    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
    $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('showhelp', 'true', time() + (3600 * 48)));
    return $response;
```

Here is my jquery snippet to do something (I am using the cookie plugin)

```
if ($.cookie('showhelp') != null) {
    alert('cookie set!');
}
```

I've also tried:

```
if ($.cookie('showhelp', {path: '/'}) != null) {
    alert('cookie set!');
}
```

I am using chrome and with the "chromekie" extension, I can see the cookie is set. When I step through the javascript debugger, the if statement evaluates to false.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Why couldn't you try with session?

Comment: Can I access the session in jquery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at documentation of [setCookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)  method there is an argument named `httponly` which determines that the cookie variable is accessible to javascript or not. In Symfony2 it is true by default. You have to set it false e.g

```
    $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('showhelp', 'true', time() + (3600 * 48), '/', null, false, false));
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. I eventually found that, but at like 3AM I had written it as `$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('showhelp', 'true', time() + (3600 * 48), null, false, false));` Omitting the `$path` and therefore it wasn't working. I had no idea what `$httponly` meant but I had a feeling that it might change something if I made it `false`

Answer (score 1):

Check the last parameter in the [setcookie function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). **httponly** is set to false by default.

From the manual:

> When TRUE the cookie will be made accessible only through the HTTP protocol. This means that the cookie won't be accessible by scripting languages, such as JavaScript. It has been suggested that this setting can effectively help to reduce identity theft through XSS attacks (although it is not supported by all browsers), but that claim is often disputed. Added in PHP 5.2.0. TRUE or FALSE

In the Symfony2 source code (v2.0.12) it says

```
//Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie
public function __construct(
    $name, 
    $value = null, 
    $expire = 0, 
    $path = '/', 
    $domain = null, 
    $secure = false, 
    $httpOnly = true
)
{
 //...
}
```

The **$httpOnly** parameter is true by default. That's why you can't access your cookie with a javascript.

To fix this you need to change your controller to:

```
// in controller
$url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('_fs_feed_show');
$response = new RedirectResponse($url);
$response->headers->setCookie(
    new Cookie('showhelp', 'true', time() + (3600 * 48),'/',null,false,false)
);
return $response;
```